# Поиск несовпавших значений одного массива в другом

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Есть следующее задание:
Компьютер генерирует пять чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 15 включительно. Человек пытается их
угадать. Программа должна выводить угаданные и неугаданные числа из тех, что сгенерировала
программа, а также ошибочные числа пользователя.
Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать это, следуя принципу Single Responsibility.

Я описал следующие методы:

1. Генератор массива из 5 случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне:

   ```
   private int getRandomNumber(int minLimit, int maxLimit) {
       maxLimit -= minLimit;
       return (int) (Math.random() * ++maxLimit) + minLimit;
   }
   ```
2. Заполнитель массива:

   ```
   private int[] getFillArray(int[] arr) {
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
           arr[i] = getRandomNumber(1, 15);
       }
       return arr;
   }
   ```
3. Поисковик совпадений:

   ```
   private Set<Integer> getMatches(int[] generated, int[] guesses) {
       Set<Integer> matches = new HashSet<>();
       for (int guess : guesses) {
           for (int generatedNumber : generated) {
               if (guess == generatedNumber) {
                   matches.add(guess);
               }
           }
       }
       return matches;
   }
   ```

И вот, к сожалению, уже который час не могу понять как описать логику поиска несовпадений(абсурд полный)...

Comment: Чему тут помогать, вы же сами ничего не сделали.

Comment: @tym32167, Ой, действительно. Сейчас отредактирую, извините за такую наглость)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная-флаг нужна в случае поиска отсутствующих в массиве значений.

Алгоритм: Перебираются значения, в случае совпадения, меняем значение флага и прерываем вложенный цикл, в ином случае происходит полный проход цикла и флаг остается с исходным значением. Далее проверяем значение флага и вносим/пропускаем предложенное число.

```
private Set<Integer> getMisses(int[] generated, int[] guesses){
    Set<Integer> misses = new HashSet<>();
    for (int guess: guesses){
        boolean found = false;
        for (int generatedNumber: generated){
            if (guess == generatedNumber){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
           misses.add(guess);
        }
    }
    return misses;
}
```